How to use Oracle 23ai JSON-Relational Duality Views?
Starting from Oracle 23 it now supports interchangeably JSON views of SQL tables, how to use it?
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/jsnvu/overview-json-relational-duality-views.html

Oracle 23 has a built-in JSON support

A JSON-relational duality view exposes data stored in relational
database tables as JSON documents. The documents are materialized —
generated on demand, not stored as such

So you can get a JSON representation of a table created in SQL out-of-the-box :
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR2(50),
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(50)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (1, 'Alice', 'HR');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID, NAME, DEPARTMENT) VALUES (2, 'Bob', 'IT');

COMMIT;

SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*)) AS EMPLOYEES_JSON
FROM EMPLOYEE;

And the response :
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"EMPLOYEE_ID":1,"NAME":"Alice","DEPARTMENT":"HR"},{"EMPLOYEE_ID":2,"NAME":"Bob
","DEPARTMENT":"IT"}]


